# Why pi() function does not work in Oracle using its JDBC driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Query 1 works fine with the Oracle JDBC driver but Query 2 doesn't. I don't understand why. Please, could someone help me?

Query 1:

```
SELECT {fn pi()} FROM table;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT pi() FROM table;
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "PI": invalid identifier

Comment: Can you give ddl of pi? And check username which connecting to Oracle

Comment: Because there is  no `pi()` (unless you created it yourself) function in Oracle.  `pi()` is javadb's function.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Not Javadb, but JDBC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no native `pi()` function in Oracle. The JDBC driver will simply replace that with a hardcoded value.

If you run

```
SELECT {fn pi()} FROM dual;
```

The driver will send:

```
SELECT ( 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375 ) 
FROM
 dual
```

to the server - that's why you can use the `{fn pi()}` against an Oracle database even though there is no such function available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this equation:

`select 2*asin(1) from dual;`

Or can define a function that returns this number as below:

```
create or replace function PI return numeric is
  Result numeric;
begin
  select 2*asin(1)
  into Result  from dual;
  return(Result);
end PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any [native function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF20031) called PI. The error suggests that you haven't created a user-defined function either.

The `{fn foo()}` syntax is [provided by JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html), thus won't work without it:

> ### JDBC escape syntax for fn keyword
>
> You can specify functions in JDBC escape syntax by using the fn
>   keyword. Syntax
>
> ```
> {fn functionCall}
> ```
>
> where `functionCall` is the name of one of the scalar functions listed
>   below.

... and following the previous link we can see that the underlying PI() function is provided by Java DB and/or Apache Derby.

Comment: Specifically, the JDBC escape functions defined in JDBC standard need to be rewritten to the data source specific functions, or - if possible - be emulated in the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

for me id did not work with numeric so i changed to float

```
create or replace function PI return float is
  Result float;
begin
  select 2*asin(1)
  into Result  from dual;
  return(Result);
end PI;
```