# update select union with the pi () function Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use the pi function within an update statement. I have OracleDeveloper Version 3.2.10.09

```
update a_oracle_table
    set test_n = sqrt(a)/pi
    from 
        select * from a_oracle_table
        where a is not null and a >0
        union all
        select pi() from dual;
```

`select pi() from dual` produces error `invalid identifier`.

How can I use pi in my update statement?

Comment: [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844777/why-pi-function-does-not-work-in-oracle-using-its-jdbc-driver)

Comment: There is no constant or function `pi` or `pi()` in Oracle SQL. You should be able to find that out in about three seconds using Google.

Comment: Maybe you saw this on the Oracle docs site - but if so [for JavaDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rreffuncpi.html), or [PBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/pbcs_common/PFUSA/pi.htm#PFUSA-planning_fuse_admin_book_cloud_357), or some other tool - rather than for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement is not Oracle at all.  The Oracle database does not support `from` in an `update` statement.

I am also not aware of a built-in `pi()` function in Oracle (although I'm sure I'll be corrected if wrong).  You can get the value with a bit of trigonometry:

```
update a_oracle_table
    set test_n = sqrt(a) / acos(-1);  -- acos(-1) = pi
```

Comment: `acos(-1)` - very nice! I'll try to remember it.

Comment: Interesting.. But   `select (22/7)-acos(-1) from dual` is Not 0. Though close to it

Comment: Ok, So, [`pi <> 22/7`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80) , I learnt 2 things today.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . Please tell me you are joking . . . and you can learn more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi.